# Strings in jquery for add content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use jquery some time ago, but im not expert i use php for example, and use many years ago, and my question it´s how i can do this in jquery

**IN PHP I CAN DO THIS :**

```
<?php

$datauser.="1";
$datauser.="2";
$datauser.="3";
$datauser.="4";



print "$datauser";
?>
```

**I want do the same for example in jQuery, but i only find the solution it´s for multiple lines add slash, for example :**

```
var datauser=jQuery("\

\<div>11111</div>
\<div>22222</div>
\<div>33333</div>
\<div>44444</div>

");
```

The question it´s, how i can do the same as in php but in jquery for i can do create differente lines, with html code for add finally div where load all contents

Thank´s in advanced, Regards

Comment: So you're asking how you can concatenate strings in JavaScript / jQuery? So that you print `onetwo` as one word... or do you want the two words on different lines?

Comment: Yes i want show as separate no as lines, yes, the same as in php but using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same but using +

```js
    var datauser = "";
    datauser += 1;
    datauser += 2;
    console.log(datauser);
```

Comment: And how i can insert this inside div as html for example

Comment: You  could use .text(yourvar)  or .html(yourvar) but maybe you should read a tutorial or something, like https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_intro.asp if your page is just one div it's $("div").text(datauser)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

Just concat the string with `+` operator.

```
var datauser=jQuery(
""
+"<div>11111</div>"
+"<div>22222</div>"
+"<div>33333</div>"
+"<div>44444</div>"
+"");
```